# React loop array and rende object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, dictionary, render

I'm trying to loop over an array with the map function in React.

when I do:

```js
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.components.map((vitamin) => {
         <p>{vitamin.ID}</p>
       })}
     </div>
   )
}
```

Nothing gets rendered. But if I try to console.log inside the map function the object key like:

```js
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.components.map((vitamin) => {
         console.log(vitamin.ID)
       })}
     </div>
   )
}
```

The vitamin id is printed in the console. So I know there's an object, but why does it not appear in my React component?

Answer (score 2):

you have to return the component/object inside each iteration of map:

```js
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.components.map((vitamin) => {
         return(
           <p>{vitamin.ID}</p>
         )
       })}
     </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: thanks. I'm new to react and always forget these little details

Comment: react is going to also complain about the key attribute or lack there of

Comment: Alternative approach: this.props.components.map(vitamin => <p>{vitamin.ID}</p>)